# Can't access the data in the redux state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

I am facing an issue while rendering a dynamic page in **NEXT.JS**.
While **clicking on a list-item DOES redirect me to the detail-page**, the data in the detail page is still not available.

I am fetching the **`poData`** in the detail-page, and if i try to log it in console, it works perfectly and logs out all the keys inside it.

However, when i try to render the individual keys in **`poData`**, for example **`poData.refId`**, an error is thrown saying that
**can't read `refId` of `undefined`**. ***(line 30)***

(`refId` is also the pageId used in redirection which proves the data is valid)
This doesn't make sense bcz in ***line 29*** the poData is logged on screen and doesn't throw the error.

Also, if i just log the `poData` without trying to access the nested data in the object, i am able to see the object containing all the nested data when it is logged on screen.

**Redux Slice Code:**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import purchaseOrdersDb from '../../db/purchaseOrders'

const initialState = [
];

const poSlice = createSlice({
  name: "po",
  initialState,
  reducers: {

    addPO(state, action) {
      // Check PO List for duplicates
      const duplicateIndex = state.findIndex(el => el.refId === action.payload.refId)
      // Add the new PO
      duplicateIndex < 0 ? state.push(action.payload) : console.log(`Duplicate Found`);;
    },

  },
});

export const poActions = poSlice.actions;
export default poSlice;
```

**Component Code:**

```
/* Next Functions */
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { refId: '1' } }
    ],
    fallback: 'blocking'
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const pid = context.params.refId;
  return {
    props: {
      pid
    }
  }
}

/* Page Component Function */
export default function POdetail(props) {

  const poData = useSelector(state => { return state.po.find(item => item.refId === props.pid) })

  poData && console.log(poData);
  poData.refId && console.log(poData.refId);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{poData.refId} </h1>
    </>
  )
}
```

[image: The screen shot of the error]
[image: Code Screenshot of the dynami]
[image: Code Screenshot of the relevant redux slice]

Comment: That error is happening on the server when Next.js pre-renders the page (and I guess occurs when you access the page directly in the browser). What is `console.log(poItemData)` returning in the terminal (where you started the dev server)?

Comment: @juliomalves is correct. This is a server-side error in next.js. Please share your entire component (expecially how you populate the props & maybe redux state server-side). Nuxt has some utility to do this [docu](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching). By default there are no props available so your selector of course return `undefined`

Comment: @juliomalves console.log(poItemData) is logging the complete object Data with all its key... However, when i try to fetch the same key individually errors are thrown.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @Thank you guys! You were right. Doesn't happen if i use getServerSideProps(). Any tips on how to tackle this.